# Variance of Binomial conditioned on Uniform

Tags: probability

> > Find the variance of the number of success that occur in $n$ independent trials with conditioning $\{U = p \}$ where $p$ is binomial and $U$ is Uniform on $[0,1]$

I am having trouble with even just the expected of this, I've tried looking at:

$$ E[P(X=i|U=p)] = \int_0^1 P(X=i|U=p) f_U(p) dp  $$

And found

$$ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{n+1} $$

This leads me to believe we want to find $E[X] = E[P(X=i|U=p)] = E[\frac{1}{n+1}]$, then $E \big[\left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^2 \big]$ to finish for the variance.  But shouldn't this have the variable $p$ included in each?

Comment: See [beta-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Related_distributions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $$X \mid p \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$$
and 
$$p \sim U(0, 1)\text{.}$$
Then
$$\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}[X \mid p]] + \text{Var}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid p]] = \mathbb{E}[np(1-p)] + \text{Var}[np]$$
Expectations are now taken with respect to $p$ because $p$ is the random portion:
$$\mathbb{E}[np(1-p)] + \text{Var}[np] = n\mathbb{E}[p - p^2]+n^2\text{Var}[p]\text{.}$$
Should be straightforward from here.

Comment: $X\sim U[0,n]$ in this case, so $var(X)=\frac {n(n+2)}{12}$.

Comment: @A.S. Meh, I'm not a fan of memorizing the conjugate prior formulas. As long as my approach above is correct, there's no reason for me to not teach this using first principals at first. I suppose if the OP is interested in conjugate priors, (s)he can read it on his/her own.

Comment: You approach is certainly correct and useful when we just need mean/variance. I simply finished the computation since OP already derived $X\sim U[0,n]$ from first principles.

Comment: @A.S. Ah, I didn't realize that and just decided to go straight toward computing the variance. Good catch.